# Possible to change tefillin from outward wrapping to inward?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, safrus

Is it possible to change the tefillin shel yad from one that wraps outward to one that wraps inward? Is it necessary to re-tie the knot?

Thanks in advance and shanah tovah.

Comment: Wrap the strap around the bayis

Comment: Are you asking if you are allowed to change your minhag? Or if it physically possible to change the strap? Or how it should be done? You will get better answers if you clarify your question (by [edit]ing the question directly)

Comment: You would need to re-tie the knot so that it will be on side closer to your body.